# 2D bouncing ball simulation - angular velocity

Tags: physics

How does angular velocity of a ball affects it's speed after a bounce? I'm trying to simulate 2D bouncing ball physics. I've found a nice solution how to calculate ball's velocity after a bounce:

```
mVelocity.x *= 1 + mi * (e - 1);
mVelocity.y *= -e;
```

where `mVelocity.x` is a component of ball's velocity parallel to the "surface" of a bounce, `mi` is coefficient of friction, `e`<=1 representsthe energy loss during the impact.

It's looks quite realistic, however I'd like to calculate angular velocity as well - and I assume it's also affecting how the ball actually bounces. I tried to achieve it using matrix found on wolfram site - http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BouncingASuperball/ (it's in the bottom of the page), but its implementation doesn't look realistic at all, ball is acting very wierdly. How can I calculate it?

Comment: [Related question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2472/how-do-i-calculate-rotation-caused-by-bounce-friction?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Forumlas here - http://www.kellegous.com/j/2006/02/19/bouncing-ball/ - seem to be working quite well, however if anyone knows an alternative version, please post it.