# Realistic bouncing ball physics

Tags: java, physics

I am trying to implement realistic physics for my game plinko. As of now i only implemented the inversion of the velocity and the distance between both objects.

```
public void changedirX () {
        velocityx =  -velocityx;
}
public void changedirY() {
    velocityy = -velocityy;
}
```

And the 'back bounce' of the ball gets implemented here:

```
if (Circle.isColliding(win1, kugel)){

        //gewinn berechnen, Kugel entfernen
    }
```

Now the ball just bounces back infinitely until it hits the bounds of the canvas. I know that i need to implement the airresistance but do not know how to start. The questions answered here on StackExchange do not have any full code unfortunately. How can i let the ball bounce realistically without just falling down vertical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the exit speed of ball bouncing off a solid surface](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/how-to-calculate-the-exit-speed-of-ball-bouncing-off-a-solid-surface)

Comment: We also have [posts on calculating air drag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=air+drag).

Comment: @Pikalek i can't use vectors in android studio, i tried everything i know and posted a question about it too here. Is there any way to calculate that without vectors or do you know a way with handling vectors in android studio (canvas)?

Comment: There are three good books on this topic. Amazon... Game Physics In One Weekend, Game Physics The Next Week, Game Physics The Rest of Your Life.. There is a physics/collision library for shapes called bullet..   https://pybullet.org/wordpress/

Comment: Do you *have* to use vectors? Yes & no. You don't have to use a vector class, but you do have to deal with X,Y coords, velocities & forces. The options are to use a predefined Vector class/struct, make your own vector class, or track the relevant info as variables pairs (i.e. posX, posY, deltaX, deltaY, etc.) Folks tend to use a vector class because it's a useful abstraction. To clarify: these are [math type vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)) not the [dynamic list type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Comment: Thank you!! @Pikalek